# Работа с радиокнопками

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Можно ли организовать такой алгоритм:

1. Нажатие на радиокнопку.
2. Она соответсвенно становится checked.
3. Далее выполняються действия (без разницы какие).
4. Через некоторое время кнопка вновь становится нe checked.

Все действия выполняются в обработчике клика этой самой радиокнопки (по крайней мере я так пытаюсь организовать). 
Вопрос: можно ли такое провернуть?

Comment: ...и в чем проблема, так и удалите с нее `radioButton.checked = false` когда это необходимо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для радиокнопки нужно отслеживать не событие `click`, а событие `change`. Всё таки выбрать радиокнопку можно не только кликом.

```js
$('[type=radio]').change(function(){
  var input = this;
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('прошла секунда');
    input.checked = false;
  },1000)
})
```

```css
label{
  display: block;
  width: max-content;
  max-width: 100%;
  user-select: none;
  margin: 0 0 .5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="radio" name="ololo" value="0" /><span>asdasdasdasd 0</span></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="ololo" value="1" /><span>asdasdasdasd 1</span></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="ololo" value="2" /><span>asdasdasdasd 2</span></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="ololo" value="3" /><span>asdasdasdasd 3</span></label>
```